# Jmeter JSR322 inside a while loop

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I cant figure out what or where I went wrong with my Jmeter Thread. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6ut8.png) this my dynamic request that calls specific variables that I need. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGWzE.png) is the conditions I added in my while loop that I called from the [Destination csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOPHa.png).

My goal is to extract the Tax rate depending on which state/city/zipcode it is, so I created a JSR322 Postprocessor Script to extract the right tax rate. Here are the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmgtr.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dptZ.png) and finally the [condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxwca.png). The next procedure would be a [Json Assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNnDv.png).

My problem is when the loop is running the first variable extracted from the tax rate file is used all throughout the loop. Here is the [Flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI6CR.png) that I created that might help you understand my flow.

TLDR:

The first variable extracted is used all throughout the loop. But it should'nt :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts.**

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> **When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So change all stuff like:

```
`${order__items__destination__stateOrProvince}`
```

to

```
vars.get('order__items__destination__stateOrProvince')
```

and it should start working as expected.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: HI! Thank you for answering my question, but after I tried doing the solution you offered the variable now returns a null. I logged the solution and it shows this:

`2021-08-17 17:36:37,590 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor for Tax Rate: Message:null
`

Comment: Hey, I didnt followed your instruction completely yesterday. I forgot to remove the curly braces and the dollar sign. Now its working. Thank you so much!